# MYSQL Having trouble doing a GROUP BY and getting data from 4 database tables

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, subquery

I have 4 database tables Rental Car Company Database, Rental Car Details Database, Rental Car Rates Database, and Booked Car Database.

There are multiple Rental Car companies and locations that have multiple cars with each car having different rates ranges,

What I'm trying to do is query all these databases to find out what locations have only trucks available for dates 03/04/22  -  03/10/22.

I want each location to show how many trucks are available at each location along with the lowest daily rate and the highest daily rate.

The problem is each truck has different prices, so when I do a GROUP BY Location its giving the high and low rate of only one truck when two are available. My low should be the lowest dailyrate of the two and the high rate should be the highest daily rate of the two for the dates i have searched.

The result I get with the data and code below is:

| Location | CarCount | Type | RentalCarCompanyName | lowrate | Highrate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LosAngeles | 1 | Truck | Car Lux | 281 | 281 |
| NewYork | 2 | Truck | Discount Car Rental | 125 | 125 |

What I'm trying to get is:

| Location | CarCount | Type | RentalCarCompanyName | lowrate | Highrate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LosAngeles | 1 | Truck | Car Lux | 281 | 281 |
| NewYork | 2 | Truck | Discount Car Rental | 125 | 169 |

I have four database tables like the following

Rental Car Company Database
Table Name: (geolocations)

| Location | Address | CompanyName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NewYork | Queens, NY 11430 | Discount Car Rental |
| LosAngeles | 1 World Way, Los Angeles, CA 90045 | Car Lux |

Rental Car Details Database
Table Name: (Cars)

| Location | Car | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NewYork | NYCar1 | Truck |
| NewYork | NYCar2 | Truck |
| NewYork | NYCar3 | Car |
| NewYork | NYCar4 | Truck |
| LosAngeles | LACar1 | Truck |
| LosAngeles | LACar2 | Truck |
| LosAngeles | LACar3 | Truck |
| LosAngeles | LACar4 | Van |

Rental Car Rates Database
Table Name: (prices)

| Car | fromdate | todate | dayrate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NYCar1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-04-01 | 199 |
| NYCar1 | 2022-04-01 | 2022-07-01 | 499 |
| NYCar1 | 2022-07-01 | 2022-12-31 | 300 |
| NYCar2 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-04-01 | 125 |
| NYCar2 | 2022-04-01 | 2022-07-01 | 399 |
| NYCar2 | 2022-07-01 | 2022-12-31 | 200 |
| NYCar3 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-04-01 | 169 |
| NYCar3 | 2022-04-01 | 2022-07-01 | 267 |
| NYCar3 | 2022-07-01 | 2022-12-31 | 250 |
| NYCar4 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-04-01 | 169 |
| NYCar4 | 2022-04-01 | 2022-07-01 | 267 |
| NYCar4 | 2022-07-01 | 2022-12-31 | 250 |
| LACar1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-04-01 | 281 |
| LACar1 | 2022-04-01 | 2022-07-01 | 267 |
| LACar1 | 2022-07-01 | 2022-12-31 | 267 |
| LACar2 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-04-01 | 300 |
| LACar2 | 2022-04-01 | 2022-07-01 | 250 |
| LACar2 | 2022-07-01 | 2022-12-31 | 267 |
| LACar3 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-04-01 | 500 |
| LACar3 | 2022-04-01 | 2022-07-01 | 700 |
| LACar3 | 2022-07-01 | 2022-12-31 | 400 |
| LACar4 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-04-01 | 500 |
| LACar4 | 2022-04-01 | 2022-07-01 | 700 |
| LACar4 | 2022-07-01 | 2022-12-31 | 400 |

Booked Car Database
Table Name: (bookings)

| Car | ArrivalDate | DepartureDate | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NYCar1 | 2022-03-01 | 2022-03-19 | Mike Smith |
| LACar2 | 2022-03-08 | 2022-03-16 | Joe Luck |
| LACar3 | 2022-03-05 | 2022-03-25 | Kelly Johnson |

The code I have tried is below

```
SELECT Cars.Location, COUNT(Cars.Location) AS CarCount, Cars.Type,
        (SELECT CompanyName
        FROM geolocations
        WHERE geolocations.Location = Cars.Location) AS RentalCarCompanyName,
                        
        (SELECT MIN(dayrate)
        FROM prices
        WHERE Car = Cars.Car AND fromdate <= '2022-03-14' AND DATE_ADD(todate, INTERVAL 1 DAY) > '2022-03-10' LIMIT 1) AS lowrate,
                       
        (SELECT MAX(dayrate)
        FROM prices
        WHERE Car = Cars.Car AND fromdate <= '2022-03-14' AND DATE_ADD(todate, INTERVAL 1 DAY) > '2022-03-10' LIMIT 1) AS highrate                  
FROM Cars
WHERE Car NOT IN (
    SELECT Car
    FROM      bookings
    WHERE      (
        ArrivalDate <= '2022-03-14' AND
        DepartureDate > '2022-03-10'
    ) 
) AND Cars.Type = 'TRUCK'                
GROUP BY Location  
ORDER BY Location ASC
```

I have a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3b39f094a4737e4de4c157fbd27433de) with data loaded

Comment: That `WHERE` clause doesn't return locations with ***only*** trucks available.  It returns locations that have ***at least*** one truck available, and any number of other vehicle types.  It also excludes vehicles even if they were only booked for a single day during that period, is that intended?

Comment: Also, looking at your test data...  `NYCar3` isn't a `Truck`, and ***is*** available for the whole period; so why is `NY` in your desired results?  `LACar4` isn't a `Truck`, and ***is*** available for the whole period; so why is `LA` in your desired results?

Comment: @Barmar your correct it returns locations that have at least one truck available. However it counts only available trucks for each location. It should exclude any vehicles that are booked any days between the searched dates.


Newy york is in the desired results because NewYork has two trucks available.  It didn't return NYCar3 , it alo didnt return LACar4 i think your not following correctly.

Comment: @webguru I didn't make those comments, MatBailie did. You really should be joining with the tables rather than using subqueries. But if you're going to use subqueries, you have to ensure that it's correlated with all the necessary columns in the main table.

Comment: @barmar oops replied to wrong person lol

Comment: @MatBailie your correct it returns locations that have at least one truck available. However it counts only available trucks for each location. It should exclude any vehicles that are booked any days between the searched dates. Newy york is in the desired results because NewYork has two trucks available. It didn't return NYCar3 , it alo didnt return LACar4 i think your not following correctly.

Comment: I didn't say `LACar4` was returned. I said `LA` was returned, even though `LACar4` is ***not*** a Truck and ***is*** available.  Also, you haven't addressed my point about vehicles that are booked for only part of your reporting period.  Please edit your question and describe the full, exact, and correct, logic you wish to implement.

Comment: @MatBailie why would someone want to see vehicles that are not available?

Comment: You're searching across multiple days, if a vehicle is booked for one of those days, it's available for the rest of them.

Comment: @MatBailie Yea but if a family is going on vacation they dont want to see cars that are book half way during thier vacation dates.

Comment: Why would someone making a booking want to find locations with Only trucks? You didn't say what your search was for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is your updated query**

```
SELECT 
  `cars`.`Location`, 
  COUNT(`cars`.`Location`) AS CarCount, 
  `cars`.`Type`, 
  `geolocations`.`CompanyName`, 
  MIN(`prices`.`dayrate`) AS lowrate, 
  MAX(`prices`.`dayrate`) AS highrate 
FROM 
  `cars` 
  JOIN `geolocations` ON `cars`.`Location` = `geolocations`.`Location` 
  JOIN `prices` ON `cars`.`Car` = `prices`.`Car` 
WHERE 
  `cars`.Car NOT IN (
    SELECT 
      Car 
    FROM 
      bookings 
    WHERE 
      (
        ArrivalDate <= '2022-03-14' 
        AND DepartureDate > '2022-03-10'
      )
  ) 
  AND Cars.Type = 'TRUCK' 
  AND `prices`.`fromdate` <= '2022-03-14' 
  AND DATE_ADD(todate, INTERVAL 1 DAY) > '2022-03-10' 
GROUP BY 
  Location 
ORDER BY 
  Location ASC
```

Comment: If a vehicle has two different prices during the reporting window, the `COUNT()` will be wrongly increased (counting number of price rows rather than distinct vehicles).  Also, in MySQL8 you can't select a column not in the GROUP BY clause, meaning that selecting `cars.type` and `geolocations.companyname` will currently generate a syntax error.